# optimal approach to animate radar in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uikit, core-animation

I'm trying to animate the heading line of a naval-style radar (the spinning part below) in iOS, like this:

[image: radar image]

My current slow, laggy, and high-overhead solution (pseudocode because the real Swift code is a little lengthy):

```
create NSTimer to call animate() every 1/60 sec
currentAngle = 0

animate():
    create UIBezierPath from center of circle to outside edge at currentAngle
    add path to new CAShapeLayer, add layer to views layer
    add fade out CABasicAnimation to layer (reduces opacity over time)
    increase currentAngle
```

What's the best way to do this without using a .gif? I have implemented the solution above, but the performance (frame rate and CPU use) is awful. How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is too complex. Don't try to re-draw your image during the animation.

Separate out the part that rotates from the part that fades in and out and animate them separately. Make each animation draw partly transparent so the other animation shows through.

Either create a static image of the part that rotates, or build a layer that creates that image.

If you create an image, you can use UIView animation to animate the rotation on the image view.

If you create a layer that draws the heading line and gradient around it, then use a `CABasicAnimation` that animates the z rotation of the layer's transform.

Comment: I was avoiding the dot that fades in/out, that's a different and easier problem. It's the static-ness of the gradient that bothers me. An image feels cold and lifeless. That's probably the only solution that's reasonable to implement. I'll try drawing a static gradient natively hoping it will give more life than a spinning PNG.

Comment: The effect of either is identical. The GIF you posted is a rotating static image too.

Comment: I'm aware that is a static image, and it looks lifeless. Stare at the center of the image - it's clear that the gradient is a rotating static image. The illusion is lost. I'll learn how to add some randomness filters/overlays/effects to my animation to make it feel more like an analog radar screen, thanks for the help.

Comment: I'd suggest using Core Image Filters that support video as part of your image. Maybe add some Perlin Noise?

Answer (score 1):

I've come to a working Swift 3 solution, thanks to [Animations in Swift / iOS 8](http://mathewsanders.com/animations-in-swift-part-two/) article :

```
    let scanInProgress = UIImageView()
    scanInProgress.image = UIImage(named: "scanInProgress.png")
    scanInProgress.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 80, height: 200)
    view.addSubview(scanInProgress)

    let fullRotation = CGFloat(Double.pi * 2)
    let duration = 2.0
    let delay = 0.0

    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options:  [.repeat, .calculationModeLinear], animations: {

      UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 1/3, animations: {
        scanInProgress.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 1/3 * fullRotation)
      })
      UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1/3, relativeDuration: 1/3, animations: {
        scanInProgress.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 2/3 * fullRotation)
      })
      UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 2/3, relativeDuration: 1/3, animations: {
        scanInProgress.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 3/3 * fullRotation)
      })

    }, completion: { 

    })
```